# Update a table based on another table value in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to insert a row in a table based on the value of another table where only I am inserting the process_master_id. other process_step_master_id and process_srno will be default 1. 
I am running the below script but I am getting "**Operand should contain 1 column(s)**" error. Where I am doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO process_step (process_master_id, process_step_master_id, process_srno)  
SELECT (id, "1","1") FROM process_master WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: This is a typo question and should not be answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it as

```
INSERT INTO process_step(process_master_id, process_step_master_id, process_srno)
   values((SELECT id FROM process_master where id = 1),1,1)
```

Comment: @Bhargav Aboti thanks...but it not solved my problem

Comment: What issue are you facing @pratikvekariya ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try below -

```
INSERT INTO process_step (process_master_id, process_step_master_id, process_srno)  
   SELECT id, 1,1 FROM process_master WHERE id=1;
```